# subtract two matrices in r

Tags: r, matrix

I have created two matrices as followings:

```
    A = c(1,2,3)
    B = c(2,4,6)
    c = as.matrix(c(3,6,9))

    z = as.matrix(cbind(A, B))
```

Now I want to take the matrix c and subtract it row by row e.g. 1-3 = -2 & 2-3 =-1 
Do get a good understanding of R programming, I would like to create a for loop. PLEASE ALL YOUR ANSWERS SHOULD IMPROVE MY FOR LOOP.

```
 for (i in 1:nrow(z))# for the rows in matrix z
  for (j in 1:nrow(c)) # for the rows in matrix c 
     {
      sub = matrix(NA, 3,2) # make a placeholder 
      sub [i,]= z[i,]-c[j,] # i am not sure whether this right
      return((sub))
   }
```

I get the following error:

```
    Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
```

I believe my for loop is wrong, can anyone help. The purpose is to learn more about R programming. Thanks

Comment: Why do you have a `return()` in a for loop? You use `return()` to return from functions. there is no where to return to in a for loop. Also, why the insistence on using a for loop? That's not very R-like.

Comment: I know, but can you correct the for loop. And thanks for mentioning that return requires a function.

Comment: You should really not use loops to solve problems of that sort in R. Arithmetics with vectors and matrices is much simpler AND much faster if done without loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write your loop that way:

```
sub = matrix(NA, 3,2) # make a placeholder 
for (i in 1:nrow(z))# for the rows in matrix z
  for (j in 1:nrow(c)) # for the rows in matrix c 
  {
    sub [i,]= z[i,]-c[j,] # i am not sure whether this right
  }
sub
```

it will end without error but you'll get:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -8   -7
[2,]   -7   -5
[3,]   -6   -3
```

which is not what you expected... because the last j was always 3 so you replaced `sub[i,]` by `z[i,]-c[3,]` which is `z[i,]-9`

Now if you replace the loops by :

```
for (i in 1:nrow(z)) #(nrow(z)==nrow(c))
  {
    sub [i,]= z[i,]-c[i,]
  }
```

then you'll have:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -2   -1
[2,]   -4   -2
[3,]   -6   -3
```

Comment: Thanks @HubertL. the answer above is wrong, because 1-3 = -2 and 2-3= -1 and as I stated my for loop is wrong. Can you correct my for loop as I want to learn this. Thanks

Comment: Thank @HuberL. Great stuff. Would you kindly ellaborate on the matrix above where I had -8, -7. How did I get this answer (knowing my solution was wrong). This will help me to understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 7):

This is a good case for `sweep`:

```
sweep(z, 1, c)
#      A  B
#[1,] -2 -1
#[2,] -4 -2
#[3,] -6 -3
```

Answer (score 2):

although not recommended, this will work

```
 sub = matrix(NA, 3,2)
 for (i in 1:nrow(z)) {
     sub[i,]=z[i,]-c[i,1]
 }
```

you don't need the second loop, also c is a column matrix.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just create a matrix where both columns are given by `c`:

```
z - cbind(c, c)
##       A  B
## [1,] -2 -1
## [2,] -4 -2
## [3,] -6 -3
```

This won't be a convenient solution for a matrix with many columns. You could use `cbind` together with `do.call` to have more flexibility:

```
z - do.call(cbind, rep(list(c), 2))
```

It is necessary to put `c` in a list. Otherwise, `rep(...)` will return a single vector instead of a list of column matrixes:

```
rep(c, 2)
## [1] 3 6 9 3 6 9
rep(list(c), 2)
## [[1]]
##      [,1]
## [1,]    3
## [2,]    6
## [3,]    9
## 
## [[2]]
##      [,1]
## [1,]    3
## [2,]    6
## [3,]    9
```

Comment: The intent is to write code for more than the two columns in the example. How would you change this for scale?

Comment: Good comment. I added a more flexible solution.